# Use perl or awk to search for numbers in a file and increase them by constant amount from the command line

Tags: perl, awk

I have a file that has a bunch of 3-digit numbers that I need to increase by a certain amount (actually, I need to increase all numbers that are greater than a certain value by a constant amount). How can I do this as simply as possible from the command line?

EDIT: To clarify, there is more text in the file than just numbers, and it's not easy to extract them as fields in awk.

Comment: You should specify the language you are interested in in the body of the question, and not only in the tags. Tags can be overlooked.

Comment: please show some sample input

Comment: Without including sample input, it's very difficult to know what makes sense for parsing said missing input.  It's possible to give a very general solution that might work, but it's almost impossible to offer a *good* solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example that will take every number (well, positive integer) in a file that is greater than 400 and add 13 to it.

```
perl -pe 's/\d+/$& > 400 ? $&+13 : $&/ge' file
```

`\d+` is the regular expression that will match any integer in your text

`$&` is a special Perl variable that contains the text that was matched by a regular expression. In this case, it would be a number.

The `/e` modifier tells Perl to *evaluate* the replacement expression. In this case, it evaluates `$& > 400 ? $&+13 : $&` to get a different number.

The '/g' modifier replaces all instances of the regular expression (the integer) on each line.

Comment: Depending on what's in the file, that may need some `\b` around the `\d+`. Also, I'm going to edit your answer to add some whitespace so its a little less like line noise.

Comment: If I have matrix of numbers, can I perform this command skipping the first column?

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
awk '$1>300{$1+=100;print $0}' file
```

Turns:

```
/home/sirch>cat file
313
233
133
413
```

into:

```
/home/sirch>awk '$1>300{$1+=100}1' file
413
233
133
513
```

Comment: The numbers are not easily extracted as fields. Using a regex is probably necessary. For example, match 3-digit numbers, check the value of the number and if it's greater than x, increment and perform the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not optimally compact, but it's the first thing I thought of:

```
perl -e 'my $file=$ARGV[0];my $amt_to_increase=$ARGV[1];
open(my $read,"<",$file) or die $!;my @lines=<$read>;close($read);
open(my $write,">","temp") or die $!;
foreach(@lines){print $write $_+$amt_to_increase . "\n";}
close($write);system("mv temp $file")==0 or die $!;' <file to read> <amount to add to each line>
```

Comment: Look into the `-p` and `-n` options in [`perldoc perlrun`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlrun) to make this script a lot shorter. The `-i` option could help, too.

Comment: @mob - Yeah, I personally favor using short, one-off scripts rather than one-liners to do stuff like this, so I'm not as familiar with the `-p` and `-n` switches as I should be.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming file has 3 digit numbers separated by newlines:

```
$ cat file|while read number;do
if [ $number -gt $minvalue ]; then
    echo $(($number+$constant))
else
    echo $number
fi
```